# A non linear ode with boundary conditions at infinity

Tags: ode, boundary-conditions, nonlinear-equations

I want to solve the non-linear ODE

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}y=a(y+y^3)$$

With the boundary conditions that 
$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} y(x) =0$$

I am not aware of any analytical method for solving this kind of problem. So, I want to solve it numerically. Which method would be suitable for this ODE? I am aware of different methods for finite boundary conditions.

Also, does anybody know if it has an analytical solution to which I could compare my numerical solution?

Comment: To me this looks more like a 2nd order (partial) differential equation in one spatial variable.

Comment: The book, "Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations" by Chapman & Hall/CRC does not seem to have a solution for this problem. Have you tried using the Runge-Kutta method. Not sure it will work for this problem, but what I remember from college, it seems like it should work for a numerical solution.

Comment: On further searching I found that it has an analytical solution of the form $\sqrt{\coth^2(\sqrt{a} x )-1 } $ which has singularity at the origin so no numerical method will work for it but the singularity is of the order $1/x$ so I made the substitution $ u=x^2 y $ which eliminates the singularity at the origin.In the new equation numerical methods apply. But now I am stuck I don't know which method is used for odes with infinite boundary conditions. The only idea that I have is that I make the solution close to 0 at the end points but  I am not aware of any numerical  for solving this nonl.

Comment: Wouldn't $y(x)=0$ satisfy this?

Comment: I need a non trivial solution

Comment: I doubt that $\sqrt{\coth^2(\sqrt{a}x) - 1}$. It seems that the solution is $y(x) = c_2 \mathrm{sc}\left(c_1 - \frac{\sqrt{a}x}{\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{1 - c_2^2}\right)$, where $\mathrm{sc}$ is a Jacobi elliptic function. This [function is odd](https://dlmf.nist.gov/22.3), so I don't think that a function satisfying the "boundary" conditions, besides the trivial one, exist.

Comment: @nicoguaro If you see the paper

Comment: @nicoguaro If you see the paper.   https://aip.scitation.org/doi/full/10.1063/1.3264737     the equation (11) is the Ode given here and the solution is given in equation (12) which is of the form I mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that paper shows that. But when I check it, it does not hold. Taking $a=1$ that corresponds to a change of coordinates, I get the following residual: $\frac{1}{\sinh^2(x) |\sinh(x)|}$. So, it does not seem to be a solution.

Comment: @nicoguaro This is something that astounded me too which is why I want to numerically solve it. The authors first non-dimensionalize the equation and get the dimensionless potential but while writing the solution to the Ode of the limiting case which only had $r_0$ they get the solution with many different constants which should not be there. I think they wanted the solution to be this so they could get the required behavior. I tried to solve it myself analytically by setting integration constants in the procedure to zero but in the end, got an imaginary solution ...

Comment: ... $i \sqrt{2}\, \mathrm{sech}(x)$ which does fit the boundary conditions but is not interesting physically.